# Python strange namespace bahavior for class factory

Tags: python, types, namespaces, factory

I tried to write simple class factory using the "type" method.
I called **myclass_factory** twice and It returned identical namespaces
(**case1** and **case2**). But the values of **myclass** attribute in that namespaces were different **(!)**.
Actualy it just what I need but I can not undestnad why I got that result.
For my udestanding, since **case1** and **case2** are not objects but just same namespace (**<class '**main**.MyClass'>**) they should refer to the same memory and should be  **case1.myclass** = **case2.myclass**

Please explain how It could be so?

```
>>> def myclass_factory(myclass):
...     return type('MyClass',(object,),{'myclass': myclass})
...
>>> class class1:
...     pass
...
>>> class class2:
...     pass
...
>>> case1 = myclass_factory(class1)
>>> case2 = myclass_factory(class2)
>>>
>>> case1
<class '__main__.MyClass'>
>>> case2
<class '__main__.MyClass'>
>>>
>>> case1.myclass
<class '__main__.class1'>
>>> case2.myclass
<class '__main__.class2'>
>>>
>>>
```

Comment: The documentation of "type()" says "With three arguments, return a **new** type object.".

Comment: You created two classes with the same class name, bound to two different variables in the global namespace, neither of which matches the class name.  It's confusing, and you have to go to some effort to do it (which you did), but it's allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually case 1 and case 2 are objects since you instantiate them. They are type objects and thus ordinary python objects. So you create two different type objects.

also see this answer: [Link to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23197122/what-are-pythons-type-objects-exactly#:%7E:text=Python%20types%20are%20ordinary%20objects,kind%20of%20objects%20can%20do.)

Also see [This description](https://www.journaldev.com/15076/python-type#:%7E:text=The%20type()%20function%20is,the%20type%20of%20an%20object.&text=When%20a%20single%20argument%20is,the%20same%20as%20the%20object.)

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially equivalent to the following "normal" code for defining classes:

```
def MyClass(object):
    myclass = class1

case1 = MyClass

def MyClass(object):
    myclass = class2

case2 = MyClass

print(case1.myclass)
print(case2.myclass)
```

Types/classes are first-class objects, and creating a new type with the same name has no effect on the previous class one with that name that was saved in the variable `case1`.